# private global vs. public global

Tags: nasm, assembly

What's the difference between the export of a symbol by using "public global" instead of "private global"?

Answer (score 0):

See [the NASM docs](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html): private segments do not get combined, public segments do. Nothing to do with symbols directly AFAIK. `global` is used for exported symbols.